# Javascript Emit called before $rootScope.$on is ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue with JavaScript. I've got an application which uses an EMIT function on load. But unfortunately the class which implements the `$rootScope.$on` is probably not ready yet. My workaround was to use a timeout but this solution is not ideal. Is there another solution? Thanks!

This function:

```
$rootScope.$on('newPrintSelected', function (event, selectedPrinter) {
    StorageModule.storage.find(collectionName, {_id : selectedPrinter.printer_hardware._id}, function(error, data){
        if (error) { //Not Found
            console.error("Ops. There is something wrong with this action...");
        }else {
                if(data[0].printOptions == null){
                    $scope.options = angular.copy($scope.default);
                    $scope.options.layerThickness = 30 - ($scope.options.layerThickness * 100);
                    $scope.persistedOptions = angular.copy($scope.default);
                    $scope.persistedOptions.layerThickness = 30 - ($scope.persistedOptions.layerThickness * 100);
                }else{
                    data[0].printOptions.layerThickness = 30 - (data[0].printOptions.layerThickness * 100);
                    $scope.options = angular.copy(data[0].printOptions);
                    $scope.persistedOptions = angular.copy(data[0].printOptions);
                }
            }
            $scope.selectedPrinterHardware = angular.copy(data[0]);
            console.warn($scope.options);
            $scope.$apply();
        });
});
```

Is not beeing called by this one:

```
$scope.setPrinter = function (printer, callback) {
        setTimeout(function(){ $rootScope.$emit('newPrintSelected', printer); }, 200);
    }
}
```

At the start up of the application I had to put the setTimeout in order to this work.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal and functionally complete code example?

Comment: Could it be that you're assigning that function to $scope.setPrinter but never actually calling it?

Comment: @sokkyoku I can see that setPrinter is being used through a log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not re-architect your code to use a service which returns the value you would send with emit? (or a promise that will fulfill with the required value).

If there is absolutely no way you can change the code generating the emit (and I really can't think of any reason why this would be) then you could store the value and listen for an event, say 'loaded', and then `$emit` at that point.